# JavaScript If/Else

Tags: javascript

I want to know how to get my javascript to display different results for the manager salaries. I have 2 If statements for it but It only displays one of the 2 conditions.

```
numberOfHoursWorked = parseFloat(numberOfHoursWorked);
basePayRate = parseFloat(basePayRate);

if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
    txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 50;
    hourlyPayRate = 20;
    jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
    hoursEligibleForBasePay = 40;
}

else (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1); {
     txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 10;
     hourlyPayRate = 20;
     jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
     hoursEligibleForBasePay = 10;
}
```

Comment: `else` doesn't have a condition directly associated with it, because it's what gets executed if the `if` condition is false

Comment: When I change the second condition from else to if, it still only displays the second if statement of the txtnumberOfHoursWorked=10 :(

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment

Answer (score 2):

This is the general structure:

```
if (condition) {
  // do this if condition is true
} else {
  // do this if condition is false
}
```

There is no condition directly for `else` because it only gets executed if the `if` condition is false.  Alternatively, you can do this:

```
if (condition) {
  // do this if condition is true
} else if (condition) {
  // do this if first condition is false and this condition is true
} else {
  // do this if first and 2nd condition are both false
}
```

but even if you did this (altered your example a bit)

```
    numberOfHoursWorked = parseFloat(numberOfHoursWorked);
    basePayRate = parseFloat(basePayRate);

    if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 50;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 40;
    }
    else if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 10;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 10;
    }
```

This doesn't make sense, since both conditions are the same thing. Either the first one will trigger and the 2nd one won't, or else neither will trigger.

**you then commented with this:**

> When I change the second condition from else to if, it still only
>   displays the second if statement of the txtnumberOfHoursWorked=10

Okay, so now you have this:

```
    numberOfHoursWorked = parseFloat(numberOfHoursWorked);
    basePayRate = parseFloat(basePayRate);

    if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 50;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 40;
    }
    if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 10;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1;
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 10;
    }
```

both of the conditions are exactly the same, so they both get executed. And you have the same vars being assigned, but with diff values. So the ones in the 2nd code block are overwriting the first. Look at your 2 conditions: they are the same.

I'm thinking perhaps this is what you're after, though I'm unsure why you are assigning a value to `jobCategorySelectedIndex` in the code block. Esp the first code block, since it would already have a value of 1 in order for the condition to be true

```
    numberOfHoursWorked = parseFloat(numberOfHoursWorked);
    basePayRate = parseFloat(basePayRate);

    if (jobCategorySelectedIndex == 1) {
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 50;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1; // <-- this is unecessary
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 40;
    } else { // <-- this gets executed if jobCategorySelectedIndex does not equal 1
        txtnumberOfHoursWorked = 10;
        hourlyPayRate = 20;
        jobCategorySelectedIndex = 1; // <-- are you sure you want to do this??
        hoursEligibleForBasePay = 10;
    }
```